# MERGE INTO DbVisualizer not worknig

Tags: sql-server, merge, dbvisualizer

Heelo everyone,

I'm trying to use Merge INTO to update my table from another table like that [example here](http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#17319.htm):

```
MERGE INTO locations l USING new_locations n         
ON (l.customer_id = n.customer_id              
AND l.location_x = n.location_x 
AND             l.location_y = n.location_y)   
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET location_count = l.location_count + n.location_count   
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (customer_id, location_x, location_y, location_count, location_name)        
VALUES (n.customer_id, n.location_x, n.location_y, n.location_count, n.location_name);
```

i'm using MSSQL and connect via DbVisualizer and ODBC brideg.

when i run the command it state: General error;

after some search i found [here](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/FAQ/Running+MERGE+statement+fail)
that you have to use this format for Mere into in VbVisualizer:

```
@delimiter %%;
MERGE x AS y<code here>
;
@delimiter ;%%
```

when i did it this way the program hang on : Parsing the script.
I tried to change the default statement separator for DbVisualizer but still no luck

/***********************************Editing ****************************/
[image: Parsing error]

If i removed the i get

```
09:27:46  [MERGE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 10713, SQL State: 37000]  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).
```

if i used the tool properties Statement Delimeters and replace the (;) with GO i get the following error

```
09:29:24  [MERGE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 0, SQL State: S1000]  General error
```

/*******************************End Editing ****************************/

can you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems that because Merge is a transact/SQL query it needs multi line to commit the transaction which DB visualizer does not allow in the free version :(

hope I could find alternative.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem executing MERGE commands with DbVisualizer Free. Can you please share the exact error you get?

Comment: @roger Thanks for your reply i edited the post to add the information you asked for.

Comment: I suggest you abandon the JDBC-ODBC driver and instead use the bundled jTDS driver. Easiest to do this is to open Tools->Connection Wizard and setup the connection. In the Driver pane pick SQL Server (jTDS).

Comment: I can not Company rules :(

Comment: The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver is generally not recommended if there is a pure JDBC driver available. The JDBC-ODBC driver is also removed in Java 8 which should be good reasons that your company revise their policy.